# How to search only in diff blocks - gvim diff

Tags: regex, linux, vim, diff

I'm trying to search a string only in "diff areas" (text blocks where there is a difference between the files).Is there a way to do this?

Comment: My best guess would be no and I'd love to be corrected. However, depending on what your actual goal is, it might suffice to use the normal command diff, pipe it to a file, and just search over that.

Comment: If you don't add context line you will only have the diff part, `set diffopt=filler,context:0`

Comment: And search only on open fold `:set fdo-=search`

Comment: @Ôrel `set diffopt=filler,context:0` gives only the diff part. but still search happens in other areas also

Comment: @D-Shan the first will fold  non diff part and with `:set fdo-=search` you will only search on open fold

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can ask vim to search only in unfold. So fold common part and search on
diff part:

```
set diffopt=filler,context:0
set fdo-=search
```

tested and it's work

Comment: `set fdo-=search` doesn't restrict searches to open folds, rather it specifies that if a search command moves the cursor into a closed fold, the fold will not be opened. On the other hand, if a closed fold contains multiple matches, it will only be "found" once, which may reduce the number of false positives. See https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Search_only_in_unfolded_text